# Setting output file for tests with SetUp method

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

Hello i have a `class` full of `testcase`-s.I want to pre-set each `testcase` output file depending on his identifier or name.

```
class SetTests {
        [SetUp]
        public async Task WriteHeader() {
            TestContext.WriteLine("${something belonging to current test}");
        }

        [TestCase]
        public void WriteContent() {
            TestContext.WriteLine("Myfirst test");
        }
        [TestCase]
        public void WriteAnotherContent() {
            TestContext.WriteLine("mysecond test");
        }
    }
```

I want  my `WriteHeader` method that gets called before each `testcase` to set the current test `Output` file  name to something that can identify the current test (`Methodinfo.Name` or whatever other unique property),and to write this as a header too in the file.

In my above example i would like after i run the tests to have:

**WriteContent.txt**

```
//----ID/name/ of test whatever-----
Myfirst test
```

**WriteAnotherContent.txt**

```
//------ID/name/ of test whatever------
  my second test
```

**P.S** I said `whatever` because i do not know what `metadata` information can you obtain in the `SetUp` method about the test that is about to run after it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to cause the output for `TestContext.WriteLine` to go to **any** file at all because it is defined as writing to the XML output report created by NUnit. The same goes for `Console.WriteLine`, which is intercepted by NUnit and also included in the XML output.

For your tests to write elsewhere, i.e. to a special file, you have to open that file yourself and write to it. So the problem is twofold...

1. How to determine which file to write to in SetUp.
2. How to ensure that each test gets that information and writes to the correct file.

Both are easy **if no tests ever run in parallel**, otherwise it's harder.

NON-PARALLEL APPROACH

`TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name` gives you the name of the current test. It is available in SetUp, TearDown and in the test itself. When tests are run sequentially, 
SetUp, Test and TearDown are run one after the other with nothing in between. You can set information in member fields in the SetUp and make use of them in the test and teardown.

Example: In SetUp, construct the file name, create it and save a TextWriter in a field for use by the tests. In the test, write to that writer. In TearDown, close it.

Another example: In SetUp, create a string writer (or just a StringBuilder) to hold the output. In the test, write to the writer (or append to the builder). In TearDown, figure out the name of the file to use and write everything out.

**NOTE: This will not work if tests are run in parallel.** Whatever info is saved in the instance may be overwritten at any time by another test in the same class. To use this approach you should **mark the entire fixture** (or every test) as `[NonParallelizable]`.

PARALLEL APPROACH

No information may be changed in the fixture instance if tests are to run in parallel. Every write statement must figure out the file to write to and append to it. Best way to do this is through a method that does the writing. It should use a lock to ensure that it is not entered by two threads at the same time. Pseudocode...

```
Lock based on the fixture instance or an object created in the constructor.
    Use test name to get file name
    Open the file for appending
    Write to the file
    Close the file
```

---

If you don't use parallel execution, there's nothing wrong with using the simpler, non-parallel approach. But if you do, be sure to mark the tests as non-parallelizable. Otherwise, you risk somebody (even your own forgetful self) coming along at a later time and adding an attribute at a higher level that makes tests default to running in parallel.